# Renaming table and view from a different database, works in editor but not from stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to run a monthly job in SQL Server to rename a table and a view in a variety of databases. The database names are stored in a table and this procedure loops through them. The table names change monthly, so I am concatenating the table names based on the current date.

This works well to creating the commands.

If I change my `EXEC` to `PRINT` and paste the results into a new query window it works great.

```
BW_Test.dbo.sp_rename 'BW_Test_DataLog_2018_05','BW_Test_DataLog_2018_06';
BW_Test.dbo.sp_rename 'BW_Test_DataLog','BW_Test_DataLog_2018_05';
```

However when I run the stored procedure it fails with the following error:

> ErrorNumber: 2812 ErrorMessage: Could not find stored procedure 'BW_Test.dbo.sp_rename 'BW_Test_DataLog_2018_05','BW_Test_DataLog_2018_06';'

Here is the stored procedure, thanks in advance!

```
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Find month and year to concatenate with table names
    DECLARE @RighNow DATE = GETDATE();
    DECLARE @LastMonth DATE = DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE());

    DECLARE @RenameView NVARCHAR(500);
    DECLARE @RenameTable NVARCHAR(500);
    DECLARE @LastMonthsName NVARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE @ThisMonthsName NVARCHAR(50);

    DECLARE @COUNTER INT = 0;

    DECLARE @MAX INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DatabaseNames)
    DECLARE @Machine VARCHAR(50);

    --Start Loop here
    WHILE @COUNTER < @MAX
    BEGIN
        SET @Machine = (SELECT DatabaseName 
                        FROM
                            (SELECT 
                                 (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))) [index], 
                                 DatabaseName 
                             FROM
                                 DatabaseNames) R 
                        ORDER BY R.[index] 
                            OFFSET @COUNTER ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY);

        SET @LastMonthsName = CONCAT(@Machine, '_DataLog', '_', YEAR(@LastMonth), '_', FORMAT(MONTH(@LastMonth), '00'));
        SET @ThisMonthsName = CONCAT(@Machine, '_DataLog', '_', YEAR(@RighNow), '_', FORMAT(MONTH(@RighNow), '00'));

        SET @RenameView = CONCAT(@Machine, '.dbo.sp_rename ', char(39), @LastMonthsName, char(39), ',', char(39), @ThisMonthsName, char(39), ';');
        SET @RenameTable = CONCAT(@Machine, '.dbo.sp_rename ', char(39), @Machine, '_DataLog', char(39), ',', char(39), @LastMonthsName, char(39), ';');

        BEGIN TRY  
            --IMPORTANT - Change the View first or you will have duplicate table names
            EXEC @RenameView
            EXEC @RenameTable
        END TRY         
        BEGIN CATCH  
            SELECT   
                ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
                ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;  
        END CATCH;

        SET @COUNTER = @COUNTER + 1
    END
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
EXEC @RenameView
EXEC @RenameTable
```

to:

```
EXEC (@RenameView)
EXEC (@RenameTable)
```

The problem is that `EXEC` has actually 2 different implementations, one for dynamic SQL (with parenthesis) and another for procedures (without).